# Remove values from xml document using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, groovyshell, jenkins-groovy

I have a groovy system batch script that needs to read in an XML document, change the values, and then save it.

I have figured out how to read the value and write it.  I cannot figure out for the life of me how to remove 'members' and its values. I need to be able to remove all the members and replace it with a custom filename I just cannot figure it out.

The XML looks like this:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>Activity</members>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <members>Task</members>
    <members>User</members>
    <members>ContentVersion</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

I would search for the name "CustomObject" and remove all the sibling's members with this string:

```
def replace = "MyCustomFile"
```

So the XML would like this:

```
<types>
    <members>MyCustomFile</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

I have tried the below code I found online

```
println "Testing Slurper"
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File(theFile))
root.types.each { types ->
println "names: ${types.name}"
    types.members.each {
        println "members: " + it.text()
    }
}

    println "Testing replace"
    def book = "Booking__c"


    def cleanUpNode(node) {
        println node
        def childs = node.children()

        def remove = []
        childs.each {
            if (it instanceof Node) {

                if (!it.children()) {
                    remove.add it
                } else {
                    cleanUpNode it
                    if (!it.children()) {
                        remove.add it
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        remove.each { node.remove(it) }
    }

    cleanUpNode root.types.name
```

It is not actually removing anything instead this was the output:

```
  <tag0:types>
    <tag0:members>*</tag0:members>
    <tag0:members>Account</tag0:members>
    <tag0:members>Activity</tag0:members>
    <tag0:members>Contact</tag0:members>
    <tag0:members>Task</tag0:members>
    <tag0:members>User</tag0:members>
    <tag0:members>ContentVersion</tag0:members>
    <tag0:name>CustomObject</tag0:name>
  </tag0:types>
```

I am still trying to get the hang of this so any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```java
List newMembersToAdd = ['myCustomFile', 'anotherCustomFile']

Node xml = new XmlParser(false, false, false).parse("myXml.xml")

xml.members?.each {
    xml.remove it
}

newMembersToAdd.each { String newMember ->
    new Node(xml, 'members', newMember)
}

new File("myNewXml.xml").withWriter { writer ->
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter( new PrintWriter(writer) )
    printer.preserveWhitespace = true
    printer.print( xml )
}
```

Comment: I do need to add new members after with a value of a file I read in.  This also makes a namespace and I do not use a namespace in my XML.  The remove method did work however

Comment: @NicolePhillips I edited the answer, I think it will not create namespaces now. But I did not undertand exactly the part about adding new `members` from a file; Will you add a single `members` tag containing all the file content? Or do you need a new `members` tag for each file line? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: No. in the second XML example in the question I will need to add a new members value there may be more than one.  So basically I need to remove old members values with new ones. There may be times when there are no members at all.

Comment: @NicolePhillips Ok I think I got it. I changed my code so you can pass a list/array of new members to add. Does it help you?

Comment: Getting this error: startup failed: 
Script1.groovy: 80: You cannot create an instance from the abstract class 'hudson.model.Node'.
@ line 80, column 5. 
       new Node(xml, 'members', newMember) 
       ^